# PHP fsockopen() fails, but telnet works

Tags: php, telnet, fsockopen

I am trying to get Sphinx Search working under Windows7.  So far everything is great except PHP cannot connect to the running service.

ONLY TELNET WORKS:

> telnet localhost 3312
>
> php: fsockopen("localhost", 3312, $errno, $errstr, 30);

I decided to test some other ports...

BOTH WORK:

> telnet localhost 80
>
> php: fsockopen("localhost", 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);

ONLY TELNET WORKS:

> telnet localhost 3306
>
> php: fsockopen("localhost", 3306, $errno, $errstr, 30);

Could the reason have something to do with the port being binary data on 3312 and 3306?

Comment: What do you mean "fails"?  What happens?  What error messages are you getting?  If the open fails, PHP should be giving you a warning message with the reason for the failure.

Comment: Warning: fsockopen() [function.fsockopen]: unable to connect to localhost:3312 (A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try and use 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost - many times this could show up dependency on the OS to do lookup on the hostname for you. If this works then it isn't PHP it is a linkage between PHP and OS.

Comment: Yes, this works for ports 3312 and 3306.  Strange that port 80 works with localhost.